# Azure Table Storage: how to save Unicode symbols during export/import?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage, azcopy

I have a table with Unicode symbols.
[image]

After it exported to JSON (I've tried Table Service REST API and AzCopy) and imported to the new table, symbols are changed.

[image]

[image]

How I can avoid it during export/import?

Comment: When I  try to add unicode symbols to Azure storage table or export it,  both can be done correclty. I use the [Microsoft Azure storage 1.1.0 version](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/).  If possible, would mind sharing the test data with text?

Comment: I didn't check it in Azure Storage Explore because it's part of automated backup.